# Is it possible to create a file that gets its contents from a program?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

In Linux, is it possible to make a file that upon being read from, gets its contents from an executable program?

Specifically, say I have program `date`. Is it possible to get the output of that program from reading a file (using something like `cat date_file`)?

For example, if this is possible:

```
$ date
05/06/18 22:51:24 UTC-7:00

…30 sec later…

$ date
05/06/18 22:51:54 UTC-7:00
```

Is this possible?

```
$ cat date_file
05/06/18 22:51:24 UTC-7:00

…30 sec later…

$ cat date_file
05/06/18 22:51:54 UTC-7:00
```

If this is possible, how would I go about achieving this?

I know that there are Linux/Unix Device Files, but I'm not sure if those would work for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - there may be a way to achieve the outcome, even though the answer to your question - as asked - is no.

Comment: In some shells particularly bash, **process substitution** `<(command)` _in a command line_ creates a temporary file (normally a pipe or socket) that reads the output of the command, such as `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you are asking (as you are asking it) is not possible.  Reading a file is an OS call which does not allow for executing a program as  part of this behaviour.

Something which might get you part of the way to your goal might be a [named pipe](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156).   A named pipe will allow you to create a virtual file (using mkfifo).   If you then have a program which outputs to that file, another distinct program can read from it.

It is, of-course, possible to evaluate a command into a file or command line and to have a file with 'variables' which you can then substitute through using another program.

Comment: If you want to get very technical, you could create a kernel module which you could make run code, and then use a device file to read it.  (This is not a good general purpose solution, and not something you would use as part of a script)  Have a  look at https://blog.sourcerer.io/writing-a-simple-linux-kernel-module-d9dc3762c234

Comment: I tried out the FIFO and it worked just how I imagined. Thanks! Now, I just need to figure out how to keep the program running in the background.

Comment: To background a program, lsuch it with an & character at the end.